# maven assembly plugin zip fle query

Tags: maven

I'm using maven assembly plugin to create a zip file that includes bin, resource, lib and _client.jar

The zip file that is created when deployed by release team creates an extra folder by the same name and all the required files are present inside that extra folder.
For ex: if xyz.zip file is created, then inside that we have another folder called xyz and then inside that xyz folder it has all the required files like bin. lib, resources etc. 
is there any way for me to get the all those file directly under xyz.zip folder instead of xyz folder. The release team wanted that way.

My Descriptor is as follows:

```
<id></id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
    <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/mule-config.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>scripts</directory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/README.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>_client-1.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: someone please look into this